# how to group cities into one value without ddl in sql

Tags: sql

I need output to be grouped by region of the country.

- The cities of "Ramat Gan", "Tel Aviv", "Jerusalem" belong to the central area.
- The city of "Eilat" belongs to the "South" area

I want to get subscribers in each area. But I don't know how to divide those two groups and count those that that have the code.

Note: DDL commands should not be used.

---

Tables: cities and subscribers

[image: Table content]

---

```
 ** select cities.city_name,count(number) as num
  FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[cities] as cities
  LEFT JOIN [tempdb].[dbo].[subscribers] as subscribers
  on cities.city_code=subscribers.city_code
  group by cities.city_name**
```

Comment: Search for similar questions before posting. Also, have data that can be accessed by your code rather than an image of the data in the spreadsheet.

Comment: edit content for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really add the region to the the `cities` table.  Absent that, you can bring it in in your query.  One method is to create a derived table with the cities and regions:

```
select v.region, count(s.number) as num
from [tempdb].[dbo].[cities] c join
     (values (1, 'Central'),
             (2, 'South'),   -- "Eilat" appears to be 2
             . . .
     ) v(city_code, region)
     on v.city_code = c.city_code left join
     [tempdb].[dbo].[subscribers] s
     on c.city_code = s.city_code
group by v.region
```